# Export-Csv outputs pscustomobject NoteProperty values inline instead new line

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I have a pscustomobject whose NoteProperty `"Members"` is populated with values within a loop.

```
$results.Members += $currentGroupMember.Title
```

When I do `"Export-Csv"` all values within `"Members"` are displayed in one Excel cell. Is it possible to have it start a new line for each value?

I tried to convert it like this:

```
$results.Members = (@($results.Members) | Out-String).Trim()
```

But it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i am doing to get the results. try the below code ( please change your for loop logic as i just get the idea from your code.

```
$results = @()

foreach($currentGroupMember in $currentGroupMembers)
{
$output = New-Object PSObject
$output | Add-Member NoteProperty -name "Memebers" -Value $currentGroupMember.Title
$results += $output
}
$results | Export-Csv C:\result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```